# ExtractIconEx: works but occasionally crashes

Tags: c++, arrays, winapi, icons, allocation

I'm extracting icons from a file and displaying them in a dialog

```
const LPCWSTR path = L"c:\path\to\file";
const UINT nIconsCheck = ExtractIconEx(path, -1, nullptr, nullptr, 0);
if(nIconsCheck > 0)
{
    HICON *iconHandles=new HICON;
    const UINT nIcons = ExtractIconEx(path, 0, iconHandles, nullptr, nIconsCheck);

    if(nIcons == nIconsCheck && nIcons != unsigned(-1))
    {

        IconSelect iconSelect(this); //dialog
        for(UINT i=0; i<nIcons; i++)
        {
            qDebug() << i;
            iconSelect.addIcon(QtWin::fromHICON(iconHandles[i])); //fromHICON returns QPixmap
            DestroyIcon(iconHandles[i]);
        }

        iconSelect.exec();
    }
}
```

The icons are being loaded correctly in the dialog, but sometimes it unpredictably causes the application to crash.

Any idea what is going on?

[Documentation on ExtractIconEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-extracticonexa)

Edit: Thanks for the quick and helpful answers. Below is the complete working code I am using atm:

```
// In my case I have a QString `filePath`
// `QString::toWCharArray` retrieves a non-0-terminated string,
// so append a 0 to `path`
std::vector<WCHAR> path(unsigned(filePath.length())+1); 
filePath.toWCharArray(path.data());
path.at(path.size()-1) = 0;

// Get number of icons in selected file
UINT nIcons = ExtractIconEx(path.data(), -1, nullptr, nullptr, 0);

if(nIcons == 0)
{
    // Try to find associated file that contains icon(s)
    // If found, `path` is replaced with the new path
    WORD index=0;
    DestroyIcon(ExtractAssociatedIcon(GetModuleHandle(nullptr), path.data(), &index));
    // Get number of icons in associated file
    nIcons = ExtractIconEx(path.data(), -1, nullptr, nullptr, 0);
}

if(nIcons > 0)
{
    // Get array of HICONs
    std::vector<HICON> iconHandles(nIcons);
    nIcons = ExtractIconEx(path.data(), 0, iconHandles.data(), nullptr, nIcons);

    for(UINT i=0; i<nIcons; i++) // Using iconHandles.size() is possibly safer,
                                 // but AFAIK nIcons always carries the correct value
    {
        // Use iconHandles[i]
        // In Qt you can use QtWin::fromHICON(iconHandles[i]) to generate a QPixmap
        DestroyIcon(iconHandles[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `iconHandles` is large enough to hold all `nIconsCheck` handles? (I am not a C++ programmer, and I don't use ExtractIconEx often, but this seems to be an issue with your code.)

Comment: `HICON *iconHandles=new HICON;` allocated enough memory for a single HICON handle, not an array of handles. You need to allocate enough memory to receive at least `nIconsCheck` handles as @AndreasRejbrand points out.

Comment: Thanks, that's it! Changed to `HICON *iconHandles=new HICON[nIcons];` (and added `delete[] iconHandles;` after the loop)

Comment: I suggest to replace the manual allocation with `std::vector<HICON> iconHandles(nIconsCheck); const UINT nIcons = ExtractIconEx(path, 0, iconHandles.data(), nullptr, iconHandles.size());`

Comment: If it occasionally crashes, it is not "working fine"!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That's what "except" means ;)

Comment: It is working fine except it isn't working fine ^_^

Comment: I rephrased that sentence :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> HICON *iconHandles=new HICON;
> ```

Here you are allocating only a single `HICON` object. If there are more than one icons in the given file, the next call to `ExtractIconEx()` creates a buffer overrun by writing past the allocated memory. You have entered the dark world of undefined behaviour.

To fix this problem, you could use a [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) like this:

```
std::vector<HICON> iconHandles(nIconsCheck); 
const UINT nIcons = ExtractIconEx(path, 0, iconHandles.data(), nullptr, iconHandles.size());
iconHandles.resize(nIcons); // Resize to the actual number of icons.

// Instead of: if(nIcons == nIconsCheck && nIcons != unsigned(-1))
if(!iconHandles.empty())
{
    // Use icons
}
```

This has the advantage over manual allocation, that you don't need to `delete` the allocated memory. The `vector` destructor will do it automatically when the scope ends. Though you still have to call `DestroyIcon()` for each icon handle.

Comment: Thanks! I would like to add that the `if(nIcons == nIconsCheck && nIcons != unsigned(-1))` check is unnecessary when allocating correctly.

Comment: @bur I have added how I would change the condition. Nothing in the reference indicates that the return value of `ExtractIconEx()` can be `-1`. Though the return value could be less than the `nIcons` argument if not all icons could be extracted successfully, so I resize the vector accordingly. There can also be a TOCTTOU race condition between the 1st and 2nd call to `ExtractIconEx`.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation you linked to:

> Pointer to an array of icon handles that receives handles to the large icons extracted from the file. If this parameter is NULL, no large icons are extracted from the file.

You only gave it a pointer to *one* icon handle.

Allocate an array as large as the function expects; from the look of it, that means `nIconsCheck` elements. A vector is good for this, as zett42 says.